# Are there any online user group meetings?

Tags: usergroups

I must admit that I am incredibly jealous of those developers who happen to live near active user groups (e.g. the ALT.NET guys in Austin).  I often read blog posts and listen to podcasts that reference these in-person meetings and find myself wishing that I could sit in and participate as well.  But it just isn't realistic to fly across the country to meet a few guys for a couple hours in a pub to talk about patterns and practices.

So I was wondering if there was a similar discussion forum for those who don't happen to live near an active user group.  After all, blogs and books only go so far, and for the most part are a one-way avenue of communication.  True, you can use comments, e-mails, tweets, and IM to get some interaction, but there is something to be said about face-to-face real-time interaction that will get lost in all of these mediums.

I guess what I'm looking for is some sort of video-conferencing deal where people who share an interest in a specific field of software development can get together to talk and interact without having to live right next door to each other.  Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to check it out, but the [Virtual ALT.NET](http://groups.google.com/group/virtualaltnet?hl=en) group sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [.NET usergroup](http://www.sldnug.net/) in SecondLife. Of course this depends how you feel about second life.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know of that.  I've never played Second Life before but I may check it out if only for the .NET user group.  I presume there's a way to chat in game via speech rather than text and a way to show images in Second Life?  If so, then that could be a potential solution.